# Rails custom validation for required fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app where a user has to fill in all survey questions (radio buttons below each question). Sample params which I'm getting from the view when the user answered only one question are:

```
{"answer_11"=>"", "answer_12"=>"", "answer_16"=>"", "answer_9"=>"Velit assumenda id.", "answer_10"=>""}
```

I know I should use the `required` options inside of a form but it won't worked with my simple form views:

```
<%= simple_form_for :test_results, url: test_results_path  do |f| %>
  <% @randomize_questions.map do |q| %>
    <%= q[:question] %>
    <%= f.input "answer_#{q[:id]}", required: true, collection: q[:answers], as: :radio_buttons, value: { question: q[:question], answer: q[:answer]} %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

create action

```
  def create
    @test_result = TestResult.new(
      answer: test_result_params,
    )
    @test_result.save
  end

  def test_result_params
    params.require(:appropriateness_test_results).permit!
  end
```

How to write such validation to prevent creation of a new record if a user did not answer all questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to see the schema of DB for that model (`TestResult`). I am assuming it has a json or somehow serialized field called `answer` that stores that hash `{"answer_11"=>"", "answer_12"=>"", "answer_16"=>"", "answer_9"=>"", "answer_10"=>""}`. And requirement is to validate that there are no blank values. you can have following validation in `TestResult` model (assuming `TestResult#answer` returns the answer hash)

```rb
validate :no_blank_answers

def no_blank_answers
  if answer.values.any?(&:blank?)
    errors.add(:answer, "cannot have blank answers")
  end
end
```

have not tested in `IRB` but should work.

Comment: Yup it works! is there any way to display that error to user somehow?

Comment: it is adding error to `answer` attribute. you can use `errors.add(:base, "cannot have blank answers")` if you want it to be not attribute specific. Either way, you can display it as you would any other rails model error. Refer to official guide if needed: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views

Answer (score -1):

You can write a validator for `TestResult` model.

`validates :answer, presence: true` - and if your result don't have a answer(field will be null) this return a error, you can saw his on `@test_result.errors`

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: No, it is not. I will always have some data inside because of my view. When user doesn't fill anything and just push submit button I will create a new records with answer as: `{"answer_11"=>"", "answer_12"=>"", "answer_16"=>"", "answer_9"=>"", "answer_10"=>""}`

Comment: You can add options which validate you empty string,

`validates :answer, presence: true, allow_blank: false, allow_nil: false`

Comment: Again, because of construction of my `form_for` it will be always some kind of string with hash inside that's why I need to create custom validator